# Deriving a resource from the controller name - plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller

Just wondering if there is a plugin out there that abstracts the process of deriving the instance of a current resource (or its class) from the current controller name?

Currently I just classify.constantize the controller name, and if that works then I test for the id paramater and load the record if it exists.

Yea, maybe it's a bit weird, but just wondered if someone's been there before and done it properly.

The reason it exists is because I need to know these objects to perform authentication on a granular level but I have about 35 different object classes so it needs to be abstract. I suppose I could assign @item to be the current item in each controller and rely on that but it seems a but unDRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[inherited_resources](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) :)

Comment: Thanks, seems like an elegant solution. I had a look at the code and yep, they're just pulling off the controller_name which is what I'm already doing. Looks like that's the way. Since I don't need any of what that plugin offers I won't use it, but it was interesting to see the details :)

Answer (score 0):

[ResourceController](http://github.com/giraffesoft/resource_controller) by James Golick.  It's out default in [Blank](http://github.com/giraffesoft/blank), a starter application.